# embed pinterest code only load first time in ajax loaded page

Tags: pinterest

I´m loading one off my pinterest boards in a page loaded with ajax, and the first time I load the page it works and displays my board as it should.

But when I load the page again then it does´t work?
I have tried to set setTimeOut and some other things but I can´t get it to load the board the second time I load the page.
This is the test code I have now:

```
<a data-pin-do="embedBoard" href="http://www.pinterest.com/pinterest/pin-pets/"></a>
<!-- Please call pinit.js only once per page -->
<script type="text/javascript" async src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

---

#### Solved

Instead off linking to pinit.js in the code I changed it to pinit_main.js and it starts to work.

Comment: This worked for me too - I had a case where I was using Pinit buttons on the images, but then later loading a Pinterest board into the page using AJAX.